# Booting Ubuntu 14.04 from External HDD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, hard-drive, uefi

My laptop has Windows 8.1 64-bit and since I have few space on my SSD, I wanted to install ubuntu in an external HDD. From the UEFI settings I disabled the safety boot, fast boot and so on, and I set the boot priority on external devices. After installing ubuntu (putting the boot loader into the external HDD), the pc starts always in Windows. From Linux live I've run Boot repair but nothing changes.

What's wrong with my procedure? 
Thanks for the help!

If I wrote on the terminal:

```
fdisk -l /dev/sdx
```

(where x is the letter of my external hdd) the output is:

```
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1   *        2046  1953455804   976726879+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sdc5       125837208  1953455804   913809298+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdc6            2048    97656831    48827392   83  Linux
/dev/sdc7        97658880   118024191    10182656   83  Linux
/dev/sdc8       118026240   125835263     3904512   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

UPDATE: from live CD, I've run Boot-repair, here the [Boot-info](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11393003/). Then I've tried to set my linux partition bootable, as @manishrw suggested but never changed, Windows always starts at boot.

```
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

/dev/sdc1            2046  1953455804   976726879+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sdc5       125837208  1953455804   913809298+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdc6            2048    97656831    48827392   83  Linux
/dev/sdc7   *    97658880   118024191    10182656   83  Linux
/dev/sdc8       118026240   125835263     3904512   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Comment: Check this discussion [Ubuntu 14.04 onto external HDD](http://askubuntu.com/questions/467803/installing-ubuntu-14-04-onto-external-hdd) whether this helps.

Comment: If it's installed at the factory, your Windows installation almost certainly uses EFI/UEFI mode. Your Linux installation may well be in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode, though. Mixing the two can be tricky. Offering a specific repair suggestion would be reckless at this point, though, because details are unclear. Please post the `RESULTS.txt` file created by the [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) or the URL that Boot Repair gave you.

Answer (score 1):

Is your external HDD set to **bootable**( has boot flag ) ? 
 You can check it via command below as root(or use sudo):

```
fdisk -l /dev/sdx
```

Replace x with your HDD letter.

Column Boot should be set for the linux root partition.
If it is set to boot, check if **grub is installed**. You can install grub (on ubuntu) via command:

```
sudo apt-get install grub-install
```

Follow this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing) for clear instructions to install grub.

You could run these commands by booting linux live USB.

P.S.  Use below command to **toggle boot flag** for partition Y on disk X. In your case if partition is sdc7, then X -> c and Y -> 7

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sdc
t #Enter command t for toggle
Partition number (1-8): 7
```

Comment: Nothing works unfortunately :(

Comment: Can you post the partition table info after running the boot toggle commands ?